# SBT + JaCoCo not covering all the "jacoco.includes" classes from different projects

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, jacoco

I have an SBT (Play Framework) multi-project application setup like the following. All the submodules are under `modules` but all the test cases that cover all submodules are in "root" project.

```
|-application
    |-src
    |-conf
    |-modules
    |   |-proj1
    |   |   |-src
    |   |   |-conf
    |   |   |-target
    |   |-proj2
    |   |   |-src
    |   |   |-conf
    |   |   |-target
    |   |-proj3
    |   |   |-src
    |   |   |-conf
    |   |   |-target
    |   |-proj4
    |       |-src
    |       |-conf
    |       |-target
    |-test
    |   |-src //I have test cases of all other projs here
    |-build.sbt
    |-plugins.sbt
```

My `build.sbt` looks something like this.

```
name := """my-proj"""

lazy val IntegrationTest = config("it") extend(Test)

lazy val commonSettings = jacoco.settings ++ itJacoco.settings ++ Seq(
  organization := "me.abc",
  version := "0.1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
  crossPaths := false,
  routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
)
lazy val appDependencies = Seq(
  cache,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19"
)

lazy val scalacheck = "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.4"

lazy val aaRoot = (project in file(".")).configs(IntegrationTest).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies,
  libraryDependencies += scalacheck % Test,
  parallelExecution in Test := false,
  javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/" + Option(System.getProperty("test.config")).getOrElse("application") + ".conf",
  parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false,
  jacoco.includes in jacoco.Config := Seq("./modules/*/target/classes/com/me/**/*"),
  parallelExecution in itJacoco.Config := false,
  itJacoco.includes in itJacoco.Config := Seq("./modules/*/target/classes/com/me/**/*"),
  Keys.fork in itJacoco.Config := true,
  Keys.fork in jacoco.Config := true
).enablePlugins(PlayJava).disablePlugins(plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin).dependsOn(
  proj1 % "compile->compile",
  proj2 % "compile->compile",
  proj3 % "compile->compile",
  proj4 % "compile->compile",
).aggregate(
    proj1,
    proj2,
    proj3,
    proj4
  )

lazy val proj1 = (project in file("modules/proj1")).configs(IntegrationTest).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
).enablePlugins(PlayJava)


fork in run := false

PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
```

As you can see, in `aaRoot`, I am trying to `jacoco.includes` the class files from other module's target folder (I have tried several other approaches, but nothing worked). All the test cases run fine, but `jacoco` could not cover anything.

```
[info] ------- Jacoco Coverage Report --------
[info] 
[info] Lines: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Instructions: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Branches: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Methods: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Complexity: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Class: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Check /Users/RP/application/target/jacoco for detail report
```

It is clear that the `jacoco.includes` not looking at any classes that I asked to look at.

I have tried many ways and tried to use `it-jacoco:cover` as well but nothing worked. Any hints or help would appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a tricky one. I solved my problem and made `jacocosbt` working with my project setup and I think my project setup is not too bad and quite normal one.

What I have is, several sub projects under a root project and all the sub projects related test cases are in root/test so that I can test cross module functional tests.

**Solution**
After reading and understanding the source code of the jacocosbt plugin, I realized that it depends on two main things. One is `classesToCover` and the other is "classes to instrument".

For the "classes to instrument" it is depending up `products in Compile` which is the "target/classes" folder in the current project you are in. In my case, "root/target/classes" has nothing and there is nothing to insturment. All my classes are in the "root/modules/module1/target/classes" etc.

All I needed is to override this behavior. The first one is easy and the second one is a work around.

In my `build.sbt`, I have to add the following modifications

```
//Gets all the target/classes directories from sub projects
lazy val myProducts = Def.task {
  streams.value.log.info("Constructing the products!!!")
  val finder: PathFinder = ((baseDirectory.value / "modules") ** "target" * "classes") filter {_.getAbsolutePath.indexOf("/project/") == -1}
  finder.get
}

//Gets the classesToCover from all the sub projects
lazy val myClassesToCover = Def.task {
  val targetFolders: Seq[java.io.File] = myProducts.value
  val inclFilters = Seq("*") map GlobFilter.apply
  val exclFilters = Seq("Routes*","*Routes*","*Reverse*","*anonfun*", "*routes*") map GlobFilter.apply

  targetFolders flatMap (classes => {
     PathFinder(classes) ** new FileFilter {
       def accept(f: File) = IO.relativize(classes, f) match {
         case Some(file) if !f.isDirectory && file.endsWith(".class") =>
           val name = sbt.inc.Locate.toClassName(file)
           inclFilters.exists(_ accept name) && !exclFilters.exists(_ accept name)
         case _ => false
  }
     } get
  })
}

//Add them as settings for my root project

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(
  jacoco.settings,
  parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false,
  Keys.fork in jacoco.Config := true,
  jacoco.classesToCover in jacoco.Config ++= myClassesToCover.value,
  products in Compile ++= myProducts.value
).enablePlugins(PlayJava).disablePlugins(plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin).dependsOn(
  module1 % "test->test;compile->compile",
  module2 % "test->test;compile->compile"
).aggregate(
    module1,
    module2
)
```

As the sbt `compile` task is dependent on `products` target, we should always run compile first like `>sbt compile jacoco:cover`.

I have tested this with only jacocosbt plugin version `2.1.6`.